# How can I prove "(⋀x. PROP ?P x) ⟹ PROP ?P ?x" in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

This is lemma `meta_spec` from the theory `Pure.thy`. It is proven by:

```
lemma meta_spec:
  assumes "⋀x. PROP P x"
  shows "PROP P x"
  by(rule ‹⋀x. PROP P x›)
```

My question is how is this method `rule` working. Does it lift over parameters and then unify with the assumption? How is this actually carried out? I don't think that the theorem `forall_elim` of the kernel is used.

Comment: @user9716869 so every meta-quantification gets converted to an schematic variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to post my comments as an answer in an attempt to close this thread. Of course, I would be happy for anyone more knowledgeable to provide amendments/further information.

`Pure.rule` is similar to classical `rule` and both are described in the document Isar-ref (more specifically, see sections 6.4.3 and 9.4.3 in Isar-ref). Further explanation can also be found in the (slightly outdated) textbook *A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic* written by Tobias Nipkow, Lawrence Paulson, and Markus Wenzel.

Indeed, as you have stated, the rule application works by unifying the subgoal with the conclusion of the rule (however, I am not familiar with all the details of the implementation). Also, to the best of my knowledge, the outer meta-quantifiers are not made implicit via the use of the schematic variables in the implementation of the method. Therefore, of course, there is no need to invoke `forall_elim` for such purpose in the implementation. In fact, if you were to provide the theorem `⋀x. PROP P x` directly to the method, it would fail on your goal `PROP P x`.

I believe, however, the reason for your question was not the lack of understanding of the main principles behind the application of the method `rule`, but the confusion related to the form of the literal fact `‹⋀x. PROP P x›`.
In the context of your application, this literal fact corresponds to the theorem `PROP P ?x` in the relevant context. You can verify this by typing `thm ‹⋀x. PROP P x›` like this:

```
lemma meta_spec:
  assumes "⋀x. PROP P x"
  shows "PROP P x"
  thm ‹⋀x. PROP P x› (*PROP P ?x*)
  by(rule ‹⋀x. PROP P x›)
```

Thus, there is nothing special about this use case from the perspective of the rule application, as `?x` is schematic in `PROP P ?x`.